# VueJs: To Disable all dates up to specific date based on condition

Tags: vue.js

I have datepicker below :

```
import Datepicker from 'vuejs-datepicker';

<datepicker :disabled-dates="disabledDates" v-model="dateTime" :format="customFormatter" width="100%" name="Date"></datepicker>
```

If CurrentDay == "Monday" then, disable all dates up to last friday of previous week. Otherwise, disable all dates up to last friday of current week.

```
export default {
    created: function() {        
      var currentDate = new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10).replace(/-/g,'-');
      var CurrentDay = moment().format('dddd'); //new Date().getDay();

      if (CurrentDay == "Monday"){
        this.disabledDates= {
            to: new Date(2020, 2, 5) // Here disable all dates up to last friday of the previous week.                                                      
        };     
      }  
      else{
        this.disabledDates= {
            to: new Date(2020, 2, 5) //Here disable all dates up to last friday of the current week.                                                        
        };  
      }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Your 2nd condition is not clear, what do you mean by: "Otherwise, disable all dates up to last friday of current week." let's say current date is today's date ie. 20-03-2020 & Wednesday, In this case which dates do you want to block

Comment: Today's date 25-032020 (Wednesday) . I want to block all the dates upto 20-03-2020 (Friday)

Comment: So, in both situation (Monday / other), you want to block till last Friday ?

Comment: Actually, my requirement is if the current day is Tuesday/Wednesday/Thursday/Friday then, I need to enable only from current week in the datepicker. If Monday then, need to enable from previous week also. Since I already made disable Saturday and Sunday with the code `days: [6, 0], // Disable Saturday's and Sunday's`, I mentioned last Friday.

Comment: sorry, still not able to get it completely. say, today date is `25-03-2020 (wed)` then you want to block all dates up to `20-03-2020 (Friday)` this case is clear to me. Let's take another eg. say `23-03-2020 (mon)`, in this case till what date you want to block ?

Comment: If `23-03-2020 (Monday)` then, I want to block all dates up to `13-03-2020 (Friday)`.
If `30-03-2020 (Monday)` then, I want to block all dates up to `20-03-2020 (Friday)`

Answer (score 0):

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-datepicker-demo-kd5g2)

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    Current date: {{ date }}
    <Datepicker v-if="date" :value="today" :disabled-dates="disabledDates"/>
  </div>
</template>
```

---

```
<script>
import Datepicker from "vuejs-datepicker/dist/vuejs-datepicker.esm.js";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      today: new Date(),
      date: null,
      disabledDates: {}
    };
  },

  components: {
    Datepicker
  },

  methods: {
    // Utility: To get date by day
    // In our case to get last week friday & this week friday
    // first param: current date / any select date as reference
    // second param: day, in our case friday ie. 5
    // third param: week, in our case last week ie. -7 (7 days from now) & current week ie. 0
    getDateByDay(currDate, day, week = 0) {
      var reqDate = currDate;
      var reqDay = day - currDate.getDay() + week;
      reqDate.setDate(reqDate.getDate() + reqDay);
      return {
        day: reqDate.getDate(),
        month: reqDate.getMonth(),
        year: reqDate.getFullYear()
      };
    },

    // Strategy / logic to block on basis of monday / other days
    strategy({ year, month, day }) {
      this.date = new Date(year, month, day);
      let getDay = this.date.getDay();
      console.log({ getDay });

      // Check if monday ie. 0
      if (getDay === 1) {
        let { day, month, year } = this.getDateByDay(this.date, 6, -7 * 2);
        // Get last friday date & block upto last friday
        this.disabledDates.to = new Date(year, month, day);
      }

      // OTHER THAN MODAY
      else {
        let { day, month, year } = this.getDateByDay(this.date, 6, -7);
        // Get current friday & block uptp current friday
        this.disabledDates.to = new Date(year, month, day);
      }
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    // invoke blocking function with any date
    this.strategy({ year: 2020, month: 2, day: 25 });
  }
};
</script>
```

*PS: You can **modify** logic as per your use case by passing desired `params`.*

Comment: @Limna D'silva Updated as per your requirement, you can try passing different dates to `strategy` fn in the mounted in the above sandbox. Thanks, also pls let me know if I missed any case